# R: How to calculate and sort two variables with a for loop

Tags: r, sorting, for-loop

I want to perform an IDW cross-validation and find out which "power"-value gives the smallest RMSE. In order to do this, I want to store the "power" and "RMSE"-values in a list and sort them by the smallest RMSE, for example

I'd like something like this:

```
     RMSE    Power
[1,] 1.230   2.5
[2,] 1.464   1.5
[3,] 1.698   2.0
[4,] 1.932   3.0
```

What I have so far is this:

```
require(sp)
require(gstat)
data("meuse")

#### create grid:
pixels <- 500 #define resolution
#define extent
raster.grd <- expand.grid(x=seq(floor(min(x=meuse$x)),
                            ceiling(max(x=meuse$x)),
                            length.out=pixels),
                      y=seq(floor(min(y=meuse$y)),
                            ceiling(max(y=meuse$y)),
                            length.out=pixels))
# convert the dataframe to a spatial points and then to a spatial pixels
grd.pts <- SpatialPixels(SpatialPoints((raster.grd)))
grd <- as(grd.pts, "SpatialGrid")
gridded(grd) = TRUE

#### perform IDW and loop through different power-values
power = seq(from = 1.5, to = 3, by = 0.5)
results=list()
results.cv=list()
for(i in power) {
    results[[paste0(i,"P")]] <- gstat::idw(meuse$zinc ~ 1, meuse, grd, idp = i)
    results.cv[[paste0(i,"P")]] <- krige.cv(zinc ~ 1, meuse, nfold = nrow(meuse),set = list(idp = i))
    }
```

Now my attempt to calculate and store the RMSE with a for-loop:

```
results_rmse <- list()
pwr <- names(results.cv)

for(i in results.cv){ #for each Element (1.5P, 2P, etc) in results.cv
    for(j in 1:length(pwr)){ #for each Power
       results_rmse <- sqrt(mean(i$residual^2))
       print(pwr[j])
       }
   print(paste("RMSE",results_rmse))
   }
```

But with this loop, it prints each RMSE individually. So I changed the code like this

```
results_rmse[[i]] <- sqrt(mean(i$residual^2))
```

But then I get an error

```
Error in results_rmse[[i]] <- sqrt(mean(i$residual^2)) :  invalid subscript type 'S4'
```

I tried several versions of the for-loop, but I couldn't even figure out how to store the values in a list, not to mention to sort them by the smallest RMSE.

Comment: In my opinion, the problem is in the list names. Try without the decimal comma. Also use `sqrt(mean(results_rmse[[i]]$residual^2))`. `i` is "1.5P" and that is not a variable name within R.

Comment: What do you mean with "without the decimal comma"? I tried it with your suggestion, but it didn't work either.

Comment: I was wrong. The problem in calling the list elements is rather that the name starts with a number. Use `paste0("P", i)` for the names. Otherwise, the calculation fix is in the answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra loop for `j` in the RMSE calculation that is not needed as far as I understand the problem. Also, I rearranged the loop in such a way that it cycles through a sequence of elements rather than calling them by their names.

```
# Data, because your script doesn't run for me. The rest is identical from your code
for(i in power) {
    results.cv[[paste0(i,"P")]]$residual <- rnorm(50)
}

# Fixed loop
for(i in 1:length(results.cv)){ 
    results_rmse[[i]] <- sqrt(mean(results.cv[[i]]$residual^2))
}
names(results_rmse) <- names(results.cv)
```

Alternatively, the `for` loop can be avoided with the `apply` function. The result is a named list corresponding to the input names, so the last line can be omitted to achieve the same `results_rmse`.

```
results_rmse <- lapply(results.cv, function(x) sqrt(mean(x$residual^2)))
```

To print the data as you showed in your question:

```
cbind(RMSE=unlist(results_rmse), Power=power)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Although the for-loop still doesn't work (I get an `Error in results.cv[[i]]$residual^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. I can avoid this error message with dropping one of the `[ ]`, like this: `results_rmse[[i]] <- sqrt(mean(results.cv[i]$residual^2))`. But then I still have `NaN` in the output. Anyway, your supposed `lapply` function worked perfectly fine, and with adding the `sort` function I finally get what I want: `Result_best <- cbind(RMSE=sort(unlist(results_rmse)))`. Thanks again!